# I get error "Failed to create /kylin. Please make sure the user has right to access /kylin" on starting kylin

Tags: kylin

Whole error is

Retrieving hadoop conf dir...
KYLIN_HOME is set to /data/kylin
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
Failed to create /kylin. Please make sure the user has right to access /kylin

I have set JAVA Home and path too but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

check the value of entry `kylin.env.hdfs-working-dir` in your `$KYLIN_HOME/conf/kylin.properties` file (by default it's `/kylin` as is shown by your error message), and check whether you have access to this directory on hdfs.